# Migrate a DFSR Server to a new one. Currently in a Hub-Spoke Configuration

Tags: windows-server-2003, dfs, dfs-r

Is there an easy way to migrate the Hub to a new server. My current one is running out of space. Do I need to redesign the configuration or can I do a migration to the new server.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm missing some detail in your question.  But can't you just do something like this:

- Bring up a new node that replicates with the current hub
- Wait for initial replication to complete
- Change topology config so the new node is the hub
- Remove the old hub from the topology

Answer (score 0):

You want the Microsoft File Server Migration Toolkit... it is free and was designed to migrate/consolodate DFS shares without impacting your end users:

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/fsmt.aspx